# Can I listen for scrolling within a div with .scrollTop (no jQuery)

Tags: javascript, html, css

**EDIT: SOLVED**

Here's the working code (checking for `perspective` support, and if it exists creating CSS parallax and listening for scrolling within div for the effect, otherwise it defaults to listening for `window.scroll`):

```
html,body {height: 100%; width: 100%;}
#nav {
    display:block;
    background:#d9ffff;
    position:fixed;
    z-index:10000;  
    width:100%;
    height:100px;
    padding-top:0px;
    transition: all 0.6s;
}
.prllx_group {
    position: relative;
    height: 100vh;
}
div {height:400px}
#one {background:#d9d9ff}
#two {background:#d9ffd9}
#three {background:#ffd9d9} 

@supports (perspective: 1px) {  

    body, html {
        overflow: hidden;
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
    }
    body {
        -webkit-transform: translateZ(0px);
        transform: translateZ(0px);
    }

    .prllx {
        position:relative;
        height: 45em;
        height: 100vh;
        overflow-x: hidden;
        overflow-y: auto;
        -webkit-perspective: 300px;
        perspective: 300px;
        perspective-origin-x: 100%;
    }
    .prllx_group {
        position:relative;
        -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
        transform-style: preserve-3d;
    }
 }
```

HTML:

```
<nav id="nav">
    <ul class="menu">
        <li><a href="#one">ONE</a></li>
        <li><a href="#two">TWO</a></li>
        <li><a href="#three">THREE</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>

<div id="parallax" class="prllx">

    <div></div>
    <div id="one" class="prllx_group">...</div>
    <div id="two" class="prllx_group">...</div>
    <div id="three" class="prllx_group">...</div>
    <div></div>
 </div>
```

JS:

```
    var container = window;
    var scrolledDiv = document.body;
    var hello = 1;

    if( typeof CSS !== "undefined" &&
    typeof CSS.supports !== "undefined" &&
    !CSS.supports("-webkit-overflow-scrolling", "touch") &&
    CSS.supports("perspective", "1px")) {
        var container = document.getElementById('parallax');
        var scrolledDiv = document.getElementById('parallax');
    };

    container.onscroll = function isTheTop() {
    var headerElement = document.getElementById('nav');
    var headerHeight = headerElement.offsetHeight;
    if (scrolledDiv.scrollTop > 80 || document.documentElement.scrollTop > headerHeight) {
        headerElement.style.background='rgba(29,29,29,0.9)'; 
        headerElement.style.paddingTop='0';
        headerElement.style.boxShadow='0 0 0.6em #1d1d1d';

    } else {
        headerElement.style.background='rgba(0,0,0,0)'; 
        headerElement.style.paddingTop='20px';
        headerElement.style.boxShadow='0';
    }
};
```

I also made sure the script is running after the HTML code, at the end of the page or deferred, then it works.

Thanks!

---

### original question:

I can't get the following script to listen for scrolling within a div, rather than window scrolling. If I try to use a CSS parallax effect (i.e. all content is inside a `div`, which stays still relative to `body`, and all content scrolls within the `div`.)

Here's my CSS

`SAME CSS AS ABOVE`

Here's my HTML:

`SAME HTML AS ABOVE`

And here's the JS (which works if I override the `@supports` –with a `!`, for example– so it defaults to an unenhanced content):

```
function isTheTop() {
    var headerElement = document.getElementById('nav');
    var headerHeight = headerElement.offsetHeight;
    if (document.body.scrollTop > 80 || document.documentElement.scrollTop > headerHeight) {
        headerElement.style.background='rgba(29,29,29,0.9)'; 
        headerElement.style.paddingTop='0';
        headerElement.style.boxShadow='0 0 0.6em #1d1d1d';

    } else {
        headerElement.style.background='rgba(0,0,0,0)'; 
        headerElement.style.paddingTop='20px';
        headerElement.style.boxShadow='0';
    }
};
window.onscroll = function() {isTheTop()};
```

I tried listening for `parallax.onscroll` (instead of `window.onscroll`) but the effect does not work.

Comment: Please add a working code snippet so we can see how it looks and figure the best way to help.

Comment: You can use the ` Element.getBoundingClientRect()` .. This gives you an object with x,y,width,height. Beware that some browsers use top,left instead of x,y.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated here
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onscroll
you should be able, if you don't want to trigger onscroll event handler if document is being scrolled, but just this element, to do this:

```
var scrolledDiv = document.getElementById("myScrollingDiv");
scrolledDiv.onscroll = function(){.....};
```

Alternatively, if this above doesn't work (I have no time to recreate your case and test it right now), you could do something like this:

```
window.onscroll = function() {isTheTop()};

function isTheTop() {
    if(scrolledDiv.scrollTop > 80) // rest of your code...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! 

I updated the code to include HTML and CSS for a working example.

I tried `var scrolledDiv = document.getElementById("parallax");
scrolledDiv.onscroll = function(){.....};` 

And I got this error in console:

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'onscroll' of null`.

Comment: @Laonikoss make sure your script comes _after_ the elements you intend to manipulate. [See this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14028959/why-does-jquery-or-a-dom-method-such-as-getelementbyid-not-find-the-element/8716680#8716680)

Comment: Sorry, my mistake - fixed the parsing error, but the effect still doesn't work. I updated the original question to reflect the changes.